# How to fix int does not contain a definition for int.TryParse()?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework

In my new CF winform I suddenly cannot code `int.TryParse()`, with VS showing the message `'int' does not contain a definition for 'TryParse'`, but in another form this is no problem. So strange!

I tracked this down, with Go To Definition, that the old form uses `int` from `C:\DOCUME~1\XPMUser\LOCALS~1\Temp\3464$CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary$v2.0.50727\System.Int32.cs` which of course has `TryParse()`, while my new code uses `int` from `C:\DOCUME~1\XPMUser\LOCALS~1\Temp\3464$mscorlib.dll$v2.0.50727\System.Int32.cs`, which has no `TryParse()`.

In the list of references of the project, there is a `mscorlib`, and by double-clicking I arrive in the Object Browser at `mscorlib [Compact Framework]`, while the object browser also shows an entry `mscorlib`, i.e. without the CF remark.

This did not help me much, hopefully someone can help me get TryParse() back.

Here is sample code with the error:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SIClient2.WebServices
{
    class Test
    {
        public Test()
        {
            int i;
            int.TryParse("123", out i); // <== 'int' does not contain a definition for 'TryParse'
        }
    }
}
```

The code without the error is part of a winform. Does that make a diff?

Comment: Did you install all .NET frameworks? If you're on Windows 7+, then they should all be there, so check. Are you overriding the method? We need to see the code itself to see what went wrong.

Comment: .NET CF only partially supports this method.  It certainly doesn't support a TryParse() overload with no arguments.  Never forget to post a snippet.

Comment: I inherited this project, and in another form of this same project int does have a .TryParse(). So how could something be installed incorrectly? This really baffles me. BTW this is XP mode under Win7. I will post some actual code.

Comment: TryParse has never existed in any version of the CF for any primitive.  If you had it, it was from some other library and you need to find that library (or just re-code it yourself).

Comment: I'd recommend Ben's answer here (not mine): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563968/c-sharp-integer-validation-compactframework/6564025#6564025

Comment: I will definitely use Ben's alternative if needed, but I find it puzzling why I should need it while it worked in other places of the same project.

Comment: I'm telling you that if it ever worked it's because you pulled in a library that had it implemented.  `TryParse` has never existed in any version of the CF, so it could have never worked just using the BCL.

Comment: Well, I posted that the other `int` is found in another library. My problem is how to get one more `int` from that lib instead from the one marked CF.

Comment: Somehow you have it referencing a desktop BCL, which allows it to compile.  At runtime under the CF it will fail. (in fact deployment should be a problem from the debugger as I would expect Studio to try to push the entire desktop framework to the device).

Comment: Ok you convinced me of using another implementation of TryParse, such as Ben's above. Thanks for your help you all. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: This turned out to be one of the things you should not do on a Friday afternoon. The solution has several projects: a client on a mobile device, hence CF. A server for web services. And a test project that calls the web services directly for easier debugging, with desktop winforms, i.e., without CF, and with int.TryParse() ... :-) We are also working on upgrading to more modern mobile devices which will hopefully avoid CF.

Comment: `Int32.TryParse("123", out i)`  should work, but not the primitive int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be one of the things you should not do on a Friday afternoon. The solution has several projects: a client on a mobile device, hence CF. A server for web services. And a test project that calls the web services directly for easier debugging, with desktop winforms, i.e., without CF, and with int.TryParse() ... :-) We are also working on upgrading to more modern mobile devices which will hopefully avoid CF.

The bottom line is that VS is not that bad, but not very easy either. Most errors are valid pointers to real problems. On the other hand regrettable that CF is so limited, while today's mobile devices are not that petite anymore.

Comment: Hilariously, I am having this same issue on a Friday afternoon. Made my day.