# Windows Mobile: "My network card connects to" registry settings

Tags: networking, configuration, registry, windows-mobile

Can anybody please tell me the registry setting(s) that are affected in Windows Mobile 6.1 when a user selects Start -> Settings -> Connections -> Wi-Fi and then changes the value of the "My network card connects to" drop down list on the "Network Adapters" tab?

I have a device that seems to default this to "The Internet" when in fact the Wi-Fi connects to the corporate network and I would like to be able to change this programatically rather than expecting 250+ users to have to do it manually every time they reboot their devices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that it is a registry change, but if it is, it's easy to determine.

1. Use the remote registry editor and attach to the device
2. Save the entire registry to a file
3. Change the network settings
4. Save the registry again
5. Use your favorite diff program to compare the two files

Comment: Chris, I tried this using the Visual Studio 2008 Remote Registry Editor but unfortunately there were even differences in the way that this saved the two registries which made it impossible to see the differences (I was using WinDiff).

Comment: Use this registry editor: http://ceregeditor.mdsoft.pl/ 
It has excellent export/import options and even does diff.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to change this setting using provisioning xml, either via [DMProcessConfigXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158518.aspx) api, or by making a setup cpf with the xml in it and running it on the device. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/marcpe/archive/2005/01/18/355158.aspx) post details how to build the xml into a cpf.

The CSP you would be interested in is the [Wifi CSP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb737539%28v=MSDN.10%29.aspx)

The 'Work Network' and 'The Internet' are metanetworks that are specified in the xml by guid, usually in the DestId parm. My answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300607/how-do-i-set-network-management-settings-or-make-the-dialog-appear-in-c-on-windo/2421523#2421523) question details the xml you can use to pass to DMProcessConfigXML to read the settings on the device to see what they are. Then you can build some xml to just set the right setting. I suspect that you would just need to set the DestId parm of the appropriate wifi entry to the 'Work Network' guid.

Answer (score 1):

According to my registry comparison on WM5 (HTC Touch HD), corroborated by values in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb737539%28v=MSDN.10%29.aspx, this setting is specified in the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ControlPanel\WiFi\Ethernet\DestID.

"{436EF144-B4FB-4863-A041-8F905A62C572}"    (default) The Internet
"{A1182988-0D73-439e-87AD-2A5B369F808B}"    Work
```

I also tried a CE2003 device (Motorola MC50), but couldn’t detect any registry changes.  The key above does not exist in the registry on this device.