# Windows Mobile 6 CM provisioning explanation

Tags: windows-mobile, provisioning

We have a provisioning XML file that in the first line sets

```
<nocharacteristic type="CM_ProxyEntries" />
```

However a need arose to expose one of the CM proxy entries, after largely trail and error and using this Question as a guide [How do I set Network Management settings or make the dialog appear in C# on Windows Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/300607/108847) we managed to get it working using the following XML:

```
  <characteristic type="CM_ProxyEntries">
<characteristic type="HTTP-{9922B32F-0721-40FA-BB11-896274A92AB0}">       
  <parm name="SrcId" value="{9922B32F-0721-40FA-BB11-896274A92AB0}"/>
  <parm name="DestId" value="{436EF144-B4FB-4863-A041-8F905A62C572}"/>
  <parm name="Proxy" value=" new-inet:1159"/>
  <parm name="Enable" value="1"/>
  <parm name="Type" value="0"/>
</characteristic>
<characteristic type="null-corp-{9922B32F-0721-40FA-BB11-896274A92AB0}">
  <parm name="SrcId" value="{9922B32F-0721-40FA-BB11-896274A92AB0}"/>
  <parm name="DestId" value="{A1182988-0D73-439E-87AD-2A5B369F808B}"/>
  <parm name="Proxy" value=" new-corp:1118"/>
  <parm name="Enable" value="1"/>
  <parm name="Type" value="0"/>
</characteristic>
```

{9922B32F-0721-40fa-BB11-896274A92AB0} is the destination id we are specifying for our GPRS connection as follows:

```
  <characteristic type="CM_GPRSEntries">
<characteristic type="TM">
  <parm name="DestId" value="{9922B32F-0721-40fa-BB11-896274A92AB0}" />
  <parm name="AlwaysOn" value="0" />
  <!-- set to 0 if no pw is used set to 1 if pw is used -->
  <!-- Set to 0 even though password is provided -->
  <parm name="RequirePw" value="0" />
  <parm name="UserName" value="xxx" />
  <parm name="Password" value="xxx" />
  <characteristic type="DevSpecificCellular">
    <snip...>
  </characteristic>
</characteristic>
```

I've now been asked to explain exactly what the provisioning XML is doing but I'm not really sure myself.

If I had to guess I'd say that

> {436EF144-B4FB-4863-A041-8F905A62C572} and {A1182988-0D73-439E-87AD-2A5B369F808B}

are hard-coded guids for "The Internet" and "work" and the XML is basically saying requests to these should be sent through our Connection {9922B32F-0721-40fa-BB11-896274A92AB0} but I'm not really sure.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those values are hardcoded on Windows Mobile