# OpenNETCF: APN Configuration Programmatically. It's possible?

Tags: windows-mobile, opennetcf

How i do implement programmatically APN automatic configuration for windows mobile using OpenNetCF?

I have 4 APN providers and I should like mark provider name and automatically set configurations and connection.

It's possible on Windows Mobile PDA?

I have this four APN [here](http://www.configurarinternet.com.br/apn-das-operadoras-vivo-tim-claro-e-oi-para-smartphone-android.html).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I actually do not know if OpenNetCF has a wrapper for setting APN but Windows Mobile devices (not Windows Phone) support WAP provisioning to setup GPRS Connections.

WAP XML can be applied locally for example using [DMProcessConfigXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc510818.aspx) API.

Here is an example to add a GPRS entry:

```
<wap-provisioningdoc>
   <characteristic type="CM_GPRSEntries">
      <characteristic type="GPRS1">
         <parm name="DestId" 
         value="{436EF144-B4FB-4863-A041-8F905A62C572}" />
         <characteristic type="DevSpecificCellular">
            <parm name="BearerInfoValid" value="1" />
            <parm name="GPRSInfoValid" value="1" />
            <parm name="GPRSInfoProtocolType" value="2" /> 
            <parm name="GPRSInfoL2ProtocolType" 
            value="PPP" />
            <parm name="GPRSInfoAccessPointName" 
            value="internet3.thephone-company.com" />
            <parm name="GPRSInfoAddress" 
            value="" />
            <parm name="GPRSInfoDataCompression" 
            value="1" />
            <parm name="GPRSInfoHeaderCompression" 
            value="1" />
            <parm name="GPRSInfoParameters" value="" />
         </characteristic>
      </characteristic>
   </characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa456052.aspx for more details.

You may also setup the connections manually and then dump them using a xml query and RapiConfig.

Yes, Trevor is right, you can use [ProcessConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300607/how-do-i-set-network-management-settings-or-make-the-dialog-appear-in-c-sharp-on). The link also shows how to get those settings. But you need to reduce the returned query result before using the values as setting xml.

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.ProcessConfiguration()` can be used in place of `DMProcessConfigXML` in managed code. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.configuration.configurationmanager.processconfiguration.aspx)